# Specifying a correlation structure for a linear mixed model using the ramps package in R

Tags: r, statistics, distance, correlation, mixed-models

I am trying to create a linear mixed model (lmm) that allows for a spatial correlation between points (have lat/long for each point). I would like the spatial correlation to be based upon the great circular distance between points.

The package `ramps` includes a correlation structure that computes the ‘haversine’ distance – although I am having trouble implementing it. I have previously used other correlation structures (`corGaus`, `corExp`) and not had any difficulties. I am assuming the `corRGaus` with the 'haversine' metric can be implemented in the same way.

I am able to successfully create an lmm with spatial correlation calculated on a planar distance using the `lme` function.

I am also able to create a linear model (not mixed) with spatial correlation calculated using great circular distance although there are errors with the correlation structure using the `gls` command.

When trying to the use the `gls` command for a linear model with the great circular distance I have the following errors:

```
x = runif(20, 1,50)
y = runif(20, 1,50)
gls(x ~ y, cor = corRGaus(form = ~ x + y))

Generalized least squares fit by REML
 Model: x ~ y 
 Data: NULL 
Log-restricted-likelihood: -78.44925

Coefficients:
 (Intercept)            y 
24.762656602  0.007822469 

Correlation Structure: corRGaus
 Formula: ~x + y 
 Parameter estimate(s):
Error in attr(object, "fixed") && unconstrained : 
 invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'
```

When I increase the size of the data there are memory allocation errors (still a very small dataset):

```
x = runif(100, 1, 50)
y = runif(100, 1, 50)
lat = runif(100, -90, 90)
long = runif(100, -180, 180)
gls(x ~ y, cor = corRGaus(form = ~ x + y))

Error in glsEstimate(glsSt, control = glsEstControl) : 
'Calloc' could not allocate memory (18446744073709551616 of 8 bytes)
```

When trying to run a mixed model using the `lme` command and the `corRGaus` from the `ramps` package the following results:

```
x = runif(100, 1, 50)
y = runif(100, 1, 50)
LC = c(rep(1, 50) , rep(2, 50))
lat = runif(100, -90, 90)
long = runif(100, -180, 180)

lme(x ~ y,random = ~ y|LC, cor = corRGaus(form = ~ long + lat))

Error in `coef<-.corSpatial`(`*tmp*`, value = value[parMap[, i]]) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 1)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In nlminb(c(coef(lmeSt)), function(lmePars) -logLik(lmeSt, lmePars),  :
  NA/NaN function evaluation
2: In nlminb(c(coef(lmeSt)), function(lmePars) -logLik(lmeSt, lmePars),  :
  NA/NaN function evaluation
```

I am unsure about how to proceed with this method. The "haversine" function is what I want to use to complete my models, but I am having trouble implementing them. There are very few questions anywhere about the `ramps` package, and I have seen very few implementations. Any helps would be greatly appreciated.

I have previously attempted to modify the `nlme` package and was unable to do so. I posted a question about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18772919/how-to-update-and-recompile-nlme-source-code-in-r), where I was recommended to use the `ramps` package.

I am using R 3.0.0 on a Windows 8 computer.

Comment: This appears to be a solution: https://github.com/toph-allen/nlmehaversine

Comment: Thanks - I am having trouble loading the package, but hopefully I can get it to work!

Comment: @NatePope I am having similar issues as when I tried to modify nlme  myself. Do you know if it is possible to download and install a modified package without checksums being a problem on Windows? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983816/checksum-errors-when-installing-nlmehaversine-from-github]

Comment: Have you tried using `remove.packages('nlme')` prior to installing `nlmehaversine`?

Comment: @NatePope Ya - I just re-did it all to double check - no sign of nlme on this computer

Comment: see answer below for a similar (but more user-friendly) implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, here is an option that implements various spatial correlation structures in `gls`/`nlme` with haversine distance.

The various `corSpatial`-type classes already have machinery in place to construct a correlation matrix from spatial covariates, given a distance metric. Unfortunately, `dist` does not implement haversine distance, and `dist` is the function called by `corSpatial` to compute a distance matrix from the spatial covariates.

The distance matrix computations are performed in `getCovariate.corSpatial`. A modified form of this method will pass the appropriate distance to other methods, and the majority of methods will not need to be modified.

Here, I create a new `corStruct` class, `corHaversine`, and modify only `getCovariate` and one other method (`Dim`) that determines which correlation function is used. Those methods which do not need modification, are copied from equivalent `corSpatial` methods. The (new) `mimic` argument in `corHaversine` takes the name of the spatial class with the correlation function of interest: by default, it is set to "`corSpher`".

Caveat: beyond ensuring that this code runs for spherical and Gaussian correlation functions, I haven't really done a lot of checking.

```
#### corHaversine - spatial correlation with haversine distance

# Calculates the geodesic distance between two points specified by radian latitude/longitude using Haversine formula.
# output in km
haversine <- function(x0, x1, y0, y1) {
    a <- sin( (y1 - y0)/2 )^2 + cos(y0) * cos(y1) * sin( (x1 - x0)/2 )^2
    v <- 2 * asin( min(1, sqrt(a) ) )
    6371 * v
}

# function to compute geodesic haversine distance given two-column matrix of longitude/latitude
# input is assumed in form decimal degrees if radians = F
# note fields::rdist.earth is more efficient
haversineDist <- function(xy, radians = F) {
    if (ncol(xy) > 2) stop("Input must have two columns (longitude and latitude)")
    if (radians == F) xy <- xy * pi/180
    hMat <- matrix(NA, ncol = nrow(xy), nrow = nrow(xy))
    for (i in 1:nrow(xy) ) {
        for (j in i:nrow(xy) ) {
            hMat[j,i] <- haversine(xy[i,1], xy[j,1], xy[i,2], xy[j,2]) 
            }
        }
    as.dist(hMat)
}

## for most methods, machinery from corSpatial will work without modification
Initialize.corHaversine <- nlme:::Initialize.corSpatial
recalc.corHaversine <- nlme:::recalc.corSpatial
Variogram.corHaversine <- nlme:::Variogram.corSpatial
corFactor.corHaversine <- nlme:::corFactor.corSpatial
corMatrix.corHaversine <- nlme:::corMatrix.corSpatial
coef.corHaversine <- nlme:::coef.corSpatial
"coef<-.corHaversine" <- nlme:::"coef<-.corSpatial"

## Constructor for the corHaversine class
corHaversine <- function(value = numeric(0), form = ~ 1, mimic = "corSpher", nugget = FALSE, fixed = FALSE) {
    spClass <- "corHaversine"
    attr(value, "formula") <- form
    attr(value, "nugget") <- nugget
    attr(value, "fixed") <- fixed
    attr(value, "function") <- mimic
    class(value) <- c(spClass, "corStruct")
    value
}   # end corHaversine class
environment(corHaversine) <- asNamespace("nlme")

Dim.corHaversine <- function(object, groups, ...) {
    if (missing(groups)) return(attr(object, "Dim"))
    val <- Dim.corStruct(object, groups)
    val[["start"]] <- c(0, cumsum(val[["len"]] * (val[["len"]] - 1)/2)[-val[["M"]]])
    ## will use third component of Dim list for spClass
    names(val)[3] <- "spClass"
    val[[3]] <- match(attr(object, "function"), c("corSpher", "corExp", "corGaus", "corLin", "corRatio"), 0)
    val
}
environment(Dim.corHaversine) <- asNamespace("nlme")


## getCovariate method for corHaversine class
getCovariate.corHaversine <- function(object, form = formula(object), data) {
    if (is.null(covar <- attr(object, "covariate"))) {          # if object lacks covariate attribute
        if (missing(data)) {                                    # if object lacks data
            stop("need data to calculate covariate")
            }
        covForm <- getCovariateFormula(form)
        if (length(all.vars(covForm)) > 0) {                    # if covariate present
            if (attr(terms(covForm), "intercept") == 1) {       # if formula includes intercept
                covForm <- eval(parse(text = paste("~", deparse(covForm[[2]]),"-1",sep="")))    # remove intercept
                }
            # can only take covariates with correct names
            if (length(all.vars(covForm)) > 2) stop("corHaversine can only take two covariates, 'lon' and 'lat'")
            if ( !all(all.vars(covForm) %in% c("lon", "lat")) ) stop("covariates must be named 'lon' and 'lat'")
            covar <- as.data.frame(unclass(model.matrix(covForm, model.frame(covForm, data, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) ) ) )
            covar <- covar[,order(colnames(covar), decreasing = T)] # order as lon ... lat
            }
        else {
            covar <- NULL
            }

        if (!is.null(getGroupsFormula(form))) {                 # if groups in formula extract covar by groups
            grps <- getGroups(object, data = data)
            if (is.null(covar)) {
                covar <- lapply(split(grps, grps), function(x) as.vector(dist(1:length(x) ) ) )     # filler?
                } 
            else {
                giveDist <- function(el) {
                    el <- as.matrix(el)
                    if (nrow(el) > 1) as.vector(haversineDist(el))                       
                    else numeric(0)
                    }
                covar <- lapply(split(covar, grps), giveDist )
                }
            covar <- covar[sapply(covar, length) > 0]  # no 1-obs groups
            } 
        else {                                  # if no groups in formula extract distance
            if (is.null(covar)) {
                covar <- as.vector(dist(1:nrow(data) ) )
                } 
            else {
                covar <- as.vector(haversineDist(as.matrix(covar) ) )
                }
            }
        if (any(unlist(covar) == 0)) {          # check that no distances are zero
            stop("cannot have zero distances in \"corHaversine\"")
            }
        }
    covar
    }   # end method getCovariate
environment(getCovariate.corHaversine) <- asNamespace("nlme")
```

To test that this runs, given range parameter of 1000:

```
## test that corHaversine runs with spherical correlation (not testing that it WORKS ...)
library(MASS)
set.seed(1001)
sample_data <- data.frame(lon = -121:-22, lat = -50:49)
ran <- 1000 # 'range' parameter for spherical correlation
dist_matrix <- as.matrix(haversineDist(sample_data))    # haversine distance matrix
# set up correlation matrix of response
corr_matrix <- 1-1.5*(dist_matrix/ran)+0.5*(dist_matrix/ran)^3
corr_matrix[dist_matrix > ran] = 0
diag(corr_matrix) <- 1
# set up covariance matrix of response
sigma <- 2  # residual standard deviation
cov_matrix <- (diag(100)*sigma) %*% corr_matrix %*% (diag(100)*sigma)   # correlated response
# generate response
sample_data$y <- mvrnorm(1, mu = rep(0, 100), Sigma = cov_matrix)

# fit model
gls_haversine <- gls(y ~ 1, correlation = corHaversine(form=~lon+lat, mimic="corSpher"), data = sample_data)
summary(gls_haversine)

# Correlation Structure: corHaversine
# Formula: ~lon + lat 
# Parameter estimate(s):
#    range 
# 1426.818 
#
# Coefficients:
#                 Value Std.Error  t-value p-value
# (Intercept) 0.9397666 0.7471089 1.257871  0.2114
#
# Standardized residuals:
#        Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
# -2.1467696 -0.4140958  0.1376988  0.5484481  1.9240042 
#
# Residual standard error: 2.735971 
# Degrees of freedom: 100 total; 99 residual
```

Testing that it runs with Gaussian correlation, with range parameter = 100:

```
## test that corHaversine runs with Gaussian correlation
ran = 100  # parameter for Gaussian correlation
corr_matrix_gauss <- exp(-(dist_matrix/ran)^2)
diag(corr_matrix_gauss) <- 1
# set up covariance matrix of response
cov_matrix_gauss <- (diag(100)*sigma) %*% corr_matrix_gauss %*% (diag(100)*sigma)   # correlated response
# generate response
sample_data$y_gauss <- mvrnorm(1, mu = rep(0, 100), Sigma = cov_matrix_gauss)

# fit model
gls_haversine_gauss <- gls(y_gauss ~ 1, correlation = corHaversine(form=~lon+lat, mimic = "corGaus"), data = sample_data)
summary(gls_haversine_gauss)
```

With `lme`:

```
## runs with lme
# set up data with group effects
group_y <- as.vector(sapply(1:5, function(.) mvrnorm(1, mu = rep(0, 100), Sigma = cov_matrix_gauss)))
group_effect <- rep(-2:2, each = 100)
group_y = group_y + group_effect
group_name <- factor(group_effect)
lme_dat <- data.frame(y = group_y, group = group_name, lon = sample_data$lon, lat = sample_data$lat)
# fit model
lme_haversine <- lme(y ~ 1, random = ~ 1|group, correlation = corHaversine(form=~lon+lat, mimic = "corGaus"), data = lme_dat, control=lmeControl(opt = "optim") )
summary(lme_haversine)

# Correlation Structure: corHaversine
#  Formula: ~lon + lat | group 
#  Parameter estimate(s):
#    range 
# 106.3482 
# Fixed effects: y ~ 1 
#                  Value Std.Error  DF     t-value p-value
# (Intercept) -0.0161861 0.6861328 495 -0.02359033  0.9812
#
# Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
#        Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
# -3.0393708 -0.6469423  0.0348155  0.7132133  2.5921573 
#
# Number of Observations: 500
# Number of Groups: 5
```

Comment: I am testing it now - it ran for my data with the gls. I haven't tested it out too much yet. I am currently trying to get it to run for mixed model (using lme).

Comment: @Sam I haven't yet tried with lme. Please note that I just modified the code to use correlation functions other than spherical.

Comment: @Sam Fixed `getCovariate` method so it will run with lme.

Comment: looks to be running - and by far the most progress on this problem. Will continue testing. Please update it if you make any more changes! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See if this answer on R-Help is useful: http://markmail.org/search/?q=list%3Aorg.r-project.r-help+winsemius+haversine#query:list%3Aorg.r-project.r-help%20winsemius%20haversine+page:1+mid:ugecbw3jjwphu2pb+state:results

I just checked and and doesn't appear that the `ramps` or `nlme` packages have been modified to incorporate those changes suggested by Malcolm Fairbrother, so you will need to do some hacking. I don't want to be considered for the bounty since I am not posting a tested solution and I didn't dream it up either.

Comment: I previously tried to modify the `nlme` package (have updated my question to show this). What do you mean when you say that ramps would need some hacking - the corRGaus command using the `haversine` metric calculates the distance I am interested in?