# How can I load custom functions into foreach loop in R?

Tags: r, foreach, regression, nlme, doparallel

I am trying to run gls models with a specific spatial correlation structure that comes from modifying the nlme package/ building new functions in the global environment from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857443/specifying-a-correlation-structure-for-a-linear-mixed-model-using-the-ramps-pack) (the answer from this post that creates new functions which allows for the implementation of the correlation structure).  Unfortunately I cannot get this spatial correlation structure to work when I run this through a foreach loop:

```
#setup example data
data("mtcars")
mtcars$lon = runif(nrow(mtcars)) #include lon and lat for the new correlation structure
mtcars$lat = runif(nrow(mtcars))
mtcars$marker = c(rep(1, nrow(mtcars)/2), rep(2, nrow(mtcars)/2)) #values for iterations

#set up cluster
detectCores()
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(6, setup_strategy = "sequential")
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)

#run model
list_models<-foreach(i=1:2, .packages=c('nlme'), .combine = cbind,
                     .export=ls(.GlobalEnv)) %dopar% {
                    
                       .GlobalEnv$i <- i
                       
                       model_trial<-gls(disp ~ wt, 
                                             correlation = corHaversine(form=~lon+lat, 
                                                                        mimic="corSpher"),
                                             data = mtcars)
                     }


stopCluster(cl)
```

When I run this I get the error message:

```
Error in { : 
  task 1 failed - "do not know how to calculate correlation matrix of “corHaversine” object"
In addition: Warning message:
In e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data) :
  already exporting variable(s): corHaversine, mtcars, path_df1
```

The model works fine with the added correlation structure :

```
correlation = corHaversine(form=~lon+lat,mimic="corSpher")
```

in a normal loop. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why your `foreach` approach doesn't work, andd I'm also not sure what you're actually calculating. Anyway, you may try this alternative approach using `parallel::parLapply()` which seems to work:

First, I cleared workspace using `rm(list=ls())`, then I ran the entire first codeblock of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19013386/6574038) where they create `"corStruct"` class and `corHaversine` method to have it in workspace as well as the *Data* below, ready for `clusterExport()`.

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(nlme))
clusterExport(cl, ls())
r <- parLapply(cl=cl, X=1:2, fun=function(i) {
  gls(disp ~ wt, 
      correlation=corHaversine(form= ~ lon + lat, mimic="corSpher"),
      data=mtcars)
})
stopCluster(cl)  ## stop cluster
r  ## result
# [[1]]
# Generalized least squares fit by REML
# Model: disp ~ wt 
# Data: mtcars 
# Log-restricted-likelihood: -166.6083
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)          wt 
# -122.4464    110.9652 
# 
# Correlation Structure: corHaversine
# Formula: ~lon + lat 
# Parameter estimate(s):
#   range 
# 10.24478 
# Degrees of freedom: 32 total; 30 residual
# Residual standard error: 58.19052 
# 
# [[2]]
# Generalized least squares fit by REML
# Model: disp ~ wt 
# Data: mtcars 
# Log-restricted-likelihood: -166.6083
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)          wt 
# -122.4464    110.9652 
# 
# Correlation Structure: corHaversine
# Formula: ~lon + lat 
# Parameter estimate(s):
#   range 
# 10.24478 
# Degrees of freedom: 32 total; 30 residual
# Residual standard error: 58.19052
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)  ## for sake of reproducibility
mtcars <- within(mtcars, {
  lon <- runif(nrow(mtcars))
  lat <- runif(nrow(mtcars))
  marker <- c(rep(1, nrow(mtcars)/2), rep(2, nrow(mtcars)/2))
})
```

Comment: thanks for the help @jay.sf  If you're interested there is a second issue I have run into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67652464/lapply-does-not-work-with-model-objects-in-r