# lapply does not work with gls + piecewiseSEM objects

Tags: r, error-handling, lapply, nlme, piecewise

I am trying to get lapply to run models (more specifically path models from the `piecewiseSEM` package). These path models use separate models (from the `nlme` package) and then are combine to build the final path model. I've had to utilize some custom made functions from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67645255/how-can-i-load-custom-functions-into-foreach-loop-in-r) to get the models to work. However, now when I try and run the path model using lapply-created objects the models do not run. However they run perfectly fine when not using lapply. I want to use lapply because I want to also utilize Parlapply later on.  Here is a reproducible example:

This is the code that I used for custom functions for the package nlme:

```
library(nlme)
library(piecewiseSEM)
#### corHaversine - spatial correlation with haversine distance

# Calculates the geodesic distance between two points specified by radian latitude/longitude using Haversine formula.
# output in km
haversine <- function(x0, x1, y0, y1) {
  a <- sin( (y1 - y0)/2 )^2 + cos(y0) * cos(y1) * sin( (x1 - x0)/2 )^2
  v <- 2 * asin( min(1, sqrt(a) ) )
  6371 * v
}

# function to compute geodesic haversine distance given two-column matrix of longitude/latitude
# input is assumed in form decimal degrees if radians = F
# note fields::rdist.earth is more efficient
haversineDist <- function(xy, radians = F) {
  if (ncol(xy) > 2) stop("Input must have two columns (longitude and latitude)")
  if (radians == F) xy <- xy * pi/180
  hMat <- matrix(NA, ncol = nrow(xy), nrow = nrow(xy))
  for (i in 1:nrow(xy) ) {
    for (j in i:nrow(xy) ) {
      hMat[j,i] <- haversine(xy[i,1], xy[j,1], xy[i,2], xy[j,2]) 
    }
  }
  as.dist(hMat)
}

## for most methods, machinery from corSpatial will work without modification
Initialize.corHaversine <- nlme:::Initialize.corSpatial
recalc.corHaversine <- nlme:::recalc.corSpatial
Variogram.corHaversine <- nlme:::Variogram.corSpatial
corFactor.corHaversine <- nlme:::corFactor.corSpatial
corMatrix.corHaversine <- nlme:::corMatrix.corSpatial
coef.corHaversine <- nlme:::coef.corSpatial
"coef<-.corHaversine" <- nlme:::"coef<-.corSpatial"

## Constructor for the corHaversine class
corHaversine <- function(value = numeric(0), form = ~ 1, mimic = "corSpher", nugget = FALSE, fixed = FALSE) {
  spClass <- "corHaversine"
  attr(value, "formula") <- form
  attr(value, "nugget") <- nugget
  attr(value, "fixed") <- fixed
  attr(value, "function") <- mimic
  class(value) <- c(spClass, "corStruct")
  value
}   # end corHaversine class
environment(corHaversine) <- asNamespace("nlme")

Dim.corHaversine <- function(object, groups, ...) {
  if (missing(groups)) return(attr(object, "Dim"))
  val <- Dim.corStruct(object, groups)
  val[["start"]] <- c(0, cumsum(val[["len"]] * (val[["len"]] - 1)/2)[-val[["M"]]])
  ## will use third component of Dim list for spClass
  names(val)[3] <- "spClass"
  val[[3]] <- match(attr(object, "function"), c("corSpher", "corExp", "corGaus", "corLin", "corRatio"), 0)
  val
}
environment(Dim.corHaversine) <- asNamespace("nlme")


## getCovariate method for corHaversine class
getCovariate.corHaversine <- function(object, form = formula(object), data) {
  if (is.null(covar <- attr(object, "covariate"))) {          # if object lacks covariate attribute
    if (missing(data)) {                                    # if object lacks data
      stop("need data to calculate covariate")
    }
    covForm <- getCovariateFormula(form)
    if (length(all.vars(covForm)) > 0) {                    # if covariate present
      if (attr(terms(covForm), "intercept") == 1) {       # if formula includes intercept
        covForm <- eval(parse(text = paste("~", deparse(covForm[[2]]),"-1",sep="")))    # remove intercept
      }
      # can only take covariates with correct names
      if (length(all.vars(covForm)) > 2) stop("corHaversine can only take two covariates, 'lon' and 'lat'")
      if ( !all(all.vars(covForm) %in% c("lon", "lat")) ) stop("covariates must be named 'lon' and 'lat'")
      covar <- as.data.frame(unclass(model.matrix(covForm, model.frame(covForm, data, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) ) ) )
      covar <- covar[,order(colnames(covar), decreasing = T)] # order as lon ... lat
    }
    else {
      covar <- NULL
    }
    
    if (!is.null(getGroupsFormula(form))) {                 # if groups in formula extract covar by groups
      grps <- getGroups(object, data = data)
      if (is.null(covar)) {
        covar <- lapply(split(grps, grps), function(x) as.vector(dist(1:length(x) ) ) )     # filler?
      } 
      else {
        giveDist <- function(el) {
          el <- as.matrix(el)
          if (nrow(el) > 1) as.vector(haversineDist(el))                       
          else numeric(0)
        }
        covar <- lapply(split(covar, grps), giveDist )
      }
      covar <- covar[sapply(covar, length) > 0]  # no 1-obs groups
    } 
    else {                                  # if no groups in formula extract distance
      if (is.null(covar)) {
        covar <- as.vector(dist(1:nrow(data) ) )
      } 
      else {
        covar <- as.vector(haversineDist(as.matrix(covar) ) )
      }
    }
    if (any(unlist(covar) == 0)) {          # check that no distances are zero
      stop("cannot have zero distances in \"corHaversine\"")
    }
  }
  covar
}   # end method getCovariate
environment(getCovariate.corHaversine) <- asNamespace("nlme")
```

Here is the reproducible example/problem with the mtcars dataset:

```
set.seed(42)  ## for sake of reproducibility
mtcars <- within(mtcars, {
  lon <- runif(nrow(mtcars))
  lat <- runif(nrow(mtcars))
})

#this makes a list of dataframes
empty_list<-replicate(n = 10,
                      expr = mtcars,
                      simplify = F)



#doing it the lapply method
model1<-lapply(empty_list, FUN = function(i)
  nlme::gls(disp ~  wt,
            correlation = corHaversine(form=~lon+lat,mimic="corSpher"),
            data = i)
)
model2<-lapply(empty_list, FUN = function(i)
  nlme::gls(wt ~  hp,
            correlation = corHaversine(form=~lon+lat,mimic="corSpher"),
            data = i)
)

model1.2<-psem(model1[[1]],model2[[1]], data = empty_list[[1]])
summary(model1.2, .progressBar = F, standardize = "scale")
```

This results in this error:

```
Error in max(sapply(nm[dfdetect], nrow)) : 
  invalid 'type' (list) of argument
```

But when I do this without lapply, it works out fine:

```
model3<-nlme::gls(disp ~  wt,
                  correlation = corHaversine(form=~lon+lat,mimic="corSpher"),
                  data = empty_list[[1]])
model4<-nlme::gls(wt ~  hp,
                  correlation = corHaversine(form=~lon+lat,mimic="corSpher"),
                  data = empty_list[[1]])


model3.4<-psem(model3, model4)
summary(model3.4, .progressBar = F, standardize = "scale")
```