# Accounting for Great Circle Distance in gls() function in R

Tags: r, geospatial, correlation, autocorrelation

I'm trying to fit a model using the `gls()` function to account for spatial autocorrelation. There are numerous examples of this, using something like `corr = corSpher(form = ~lon + lat)`. The challenge however is that my data is fully global, such that I think I need to be calculating something like the Great Circle Distance or Haversine distance, rather than simply the Euclidean distance. The challenge is that coordinates with a longitude of -179 and +179 will incorrectly be assumed to be very far apart, unless I can model these as coordinates.

Is there are way to account for this in gls, or perhaps in a different R function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857443/specifying-a-correlation-structure-for-a-linear-mixed-model-using-the-ramps-pack ; https://github.com/biometry/FReibier/blob/master/FReibier/R/corHaversine.R ?